# JavaScript - Giving an array of objects a rating based on numerical value and incrementing the rating for duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
    {
        "name": John,
        "awards": 3
    },
    {
        "name": Pat,
        "awards": 9
    },
    {
        "name": Mary,
        "awards": 2
    },
    {
        "name": Joe,
        "awards": 1
    },
    {
        "name": Kathleen,
        "awards": 1
    },
    {
        "name": Teddy,
        "awards": 1
    },

]
```

Hi, how do i sort this array of objects and add a new attribute to each object called score, giving each of them a score between 1 and 6, if some objects have the same score the next score needs to increment by the number of value with the same score.
This is an example of how i need the output to be. Thanks

```
    {
        "name": John,
        "awards": 3,
        "score": 5
    },
    {
        "name": Pat,
        "awards": 9,
        "score": 6

    },
    {
        "name": Mary,
        "awards": 2,
        "score": 4

    },
    {
        "name": Joe,
        "awards": 1,
        "score": 1

    },
    {
        "name": Kathleen,
        "awards": 1,
        "score": 1

    },
    {
        "name": Teddy,
        "awards": 1,
        "score": 1

    },

]
```

Comment: Have you tried writing code yet? If so, can you share it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort, then assign the index as the score, unless the previous entry is equal, in that case take over their score:

```
 const byAward = (a, b) => a.awards - b.awards;
 winners.sort(byAward);
 winners.forEach((winner, index) => {
    if (index === 0 || byAward(winner, winners[index - 1]) !== 0) 
      winner.score = index + 1;
    else 
      winner.score = winners[index - 1].score;
 });
```

Comment: Retaining the original sort order is left as an exercise for the reader. Hint: it just takes another `[... ]` and chaining.

Comment: Thanks man!!  :)